# After logging in with my AD credentials, why can I not change any settings?

Tags: permissions, login, 22.04, active-directory, sssd

I've been setting up a new machine with Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop. And since I'm on the IT team, I've been using it as an opportunity to broaden my knowledge of configuring Ubuntu for a work environment, as well as figure out how to correctly configure Ubuntu in case some other researcher/engineer in the organization ever wants to switch to Ubuntu.

One of the aspects I'm trying to get right is authenticating users using Active Directory.
I've got it working where I can log in using my AD creds, but then I can't seem to configure my settings any further.

#### Setup

My procedure to set up the machine was:

1. Install Ubuntu 22.04, and create a local admin user (`admin`)
2. Sign in to `admin`.
3. Install updates.
4. Install AD-related stuff for SSSD.

   ```
   sudo apt install sssd-ad sssd-tools realmd adcli adsys
   ```
5. Join the domain.

   ```
   sudo realm -v join -U [MY-AD-ADMIN] organization.org
   ```
6. Make some adjustments to the auto-generated `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`, with the final result being...

   ```
   [nss]
   allowed_shells = /bin/sh,/bin/csh,/bin/bash,/bin/ksh,/bin/fish
   #debug_level = 0x0200

   [sssd]
   services = nss, pam, autofs
   config_file_version = 2
   domains = organization.org
   default_domain_suffix = organization.org
   full_name_format = %1$s
   #debug_level = 0x0200

   [domain/organization.org]
   ad_domain = organization.org
   use_fully_qualified_names = True
   realmd_tags = joined-with-adcli manages-system
   krb5_realm = ORGANIZATION.ORG
   krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
   cache_credentials = True
   ldap_id_mapping = False
   id_provider = ad
   access_provider = ad
   pwd_expiration_warning = 0
   default_shell = /bin/bash
   override_homedir = /home/%u
   fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
   debug_level = 0x0400
   ```

   - I set `default_domain_suffix` to the value you see so that I can log in with `ad-username` instead of having to type out `ad-username@organization.org`.
   - I set `full_name_format` and `override_homedir` to the values you see so that when I log in with my AD User, the home directory and file ownership also only have `ad-username` instead of `ad-username@organization.org`.

With all of this set up using my `admin` user, I logged out then logged back in using my AD creds. While the login process was completing, I saw a message that my home directory was being created, user settings applied, and thought all was good until I went to actually change settings.

#### The Problem(s)

After logging in as `ad-username`, I opened "Settings" and went about doing things like changing my desktop background, window appearance/colors, dock settings, favorited applications, notifications, power settings...

> The exception seems to be that I can change my display's scaling from 200% to 100%, and that stays if I log out and log back in.
> I can interact with the slider for "Fractional Scaling", but the "Scale" setting doesn't change to a dropdown, and the slider reverts back to **off** if I navigate to a different section of Settings.
> I also cannot enable the "Night Light" setting.

Basically, anything and everything in settings could either not be changed, or the GUI *showed* it changing but reverted the changes as soon as I navigated away.

I would appreciate any suggestions on where to look for the root cause.

- **Is my machine trying to save my user's settings back to the AD servers?**
- **Did I forget some property in my `sssd.conf`?**
- **Is there something in Ubuntu that is preventing my AD User from changing any settings?**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an *answer*, per se, but I did resolve my issue.
.... I do wish someone could explain why things weren't working.

Anyway, solution!

#### Solution

I built a new `sssd.conf` file, this one using LDAP instead of AD options.
The `[nss]` and `[sssd]` sections of the configuration file stayed the same, while the `[domain/XXXX]` section was redone as below.

```
[domain/organization.org]
use_fully_qualified_names = True
realmd_tags = joined-with-adcli manages-system
krb5_realm = ORGANIZATION.ORG
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True

ldap_uri = ldap://ldap.organization.org:389/
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
ldap_tls_reqcert = never
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts
ldap_schema = ad
ldap_default_bind_dn = CN=ldap_sssd,OU=SpecialUsers,DC=organization,DC=org
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = MySecretPassword!SSHHHHHH
ldap_search_base = OU=AllUsers,DC=organization,DC=org
ldap_access_order = expire
ldap_account_expire_policy = ad
ldap_force_upper_case_realm = true
ldap_id_mapping = False

id_provider = ldap
autofs_provider = ldap
cache_credentials = True
pwd_expiration_warning = 0
default_shell = /bin/bash
override_homedir = /home/%u
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d

debug_level = 0x0400
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my issue with stop & disable systemd-resolved service and add domain controller IP as nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf.